# I want to do a binary search over a large file, should I mmap the entire file or repeatedly mmap small blocks instead?

Tags: file, binary-search, mmap

I have a sorted large file divided into multiple blocks of equal size and want to perform a binary search over it. So, I am considering whether to mmap the entire file at once or repeatedly mmap small blocks instead? I am thinking if I mmap the entire file that will take a lot of memory and if I repeatedly mmap small blocks that would take lot of time. Which is better?

Comment: Found tthe answer??? @Anon

Comment: @XaviFont Didn't do any benchmarks but from all the advice it seems mmaping the entire file is just more convenient and doesn't hurt much, so have gone with that.